# Facebook graph api last known location

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can i get the last known location with the Facebook API? I tried

```
 NSLog(@"%@", user.location);
```

But i receiving, null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would need more information. What method are you calling this in?

You should be getting this information from an FBRequest which will return an NSDictionary on success. Then you can do...

```
[[dict objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Which will return the name of their location.

Comment: I assume then that the user doesn't have a location set in their profile. This location isn't the most recent location, but rather their current city that they set on FB.. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.1/protocol/FBGraphUser/#location